# Java add group to directory permission list

Tags: java, permissions, directory

I'm working to grant specific groups permission to the top level of a directory structure that I am creating with `file.mkdirs()`. I have found how to change the owner of the directory but that's NOT what I need, I need to add a group to the list of those with access to the directory. Specifically this is for a Windows system and a folder structure that I am creating. I need to add groups to the folder's security section to allow them to read and write to all of the sub directories. Is this even possible?

Comment: Heer are some useful links:Oracle's Java tutorial topic [Managing Metadata (File and File Store Attributes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) and the file APIs at [java.nio.file.attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/package-summary.html).

Comment: @gfos That's not quite what I'm looking for. I do not want to change the owner. Also I should have added that this is for a Windows system.

Comment: The example code for the [AclFileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html) should help you getting started. Try reading and printing the existing ACEs first to see which permissions and flags you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Robyte pointing me in the right direction. Below is the unfinished code, I need to do some refactoring, but it is getting me most of what I need.

```
try {
    Path path = file.toPath();

    AclFileAttributeView aclView = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, AclFileAttributeView.class);
    if(aclView == null)
    {
        System.out.format("ACL View not supported");
    }

    UserPrincipal up = FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService().lookupPrincipalByName("username");
    Set<AclEntryPermission> aep = EnumSet.of(READ_DATA,WRITE_DATA);

    AclEntry builder = AclEntry.newBuilder().setType(AclEntryType.ALLOW).
            setPrincipal(up).setPermissions(aep).build();

    List<AclEntry> acl = aclView.getAcl();
    acl.add(0,builder);
    aclView.setAcl(acl);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PermissionsUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```